# Dapper async hangs

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, dapper, mysql.data

I updated `Mysql.Data` to use new mysql 8.* and since this update `queryAsync` hangs forever.

Here is my method:

```
public async Task<bool> IsLiveResultsEnabled(Guid clientId)
{          
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var result = await connection.QueryAsync<bool>(
            @"SELECT someField FROM someTable WHERE Id = @clientId",
            new
            {
                clientId
            });

        var resultValue = result.FirstOrDefault();

        return resultValue;
    }
}
```

when debugging code hangs on this line await `connection.QueryAsync<bool>`

So I tried to debug this method in dapper and it hangs on last line of the function [image]

After this line when I try to step to the next line it hangs.

Here is the call of `IsLiveResultsEnabled`:

```
private bool IsGapLiveSyncEnabled(Guid clientId)
{
    return _clientsService
        .IsLiveResultsEnabled(clientId)
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
}
```

I also tried to use

```
_clientsService
    .IsLiveResultsEnabled(clientId)
    .ConfigureAwait(false)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Make `IsGapLiveSyncEnabled` async and do `return await _clientService.IsLiveResultsEnabled(clientId);` Otherwise you can get a classic async deadlock

Comment: The reason this is probably happening now is that MySql.Data <= 8.0.32 had "Async" methods that ran synchronously: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111. In 8.0.33, they actually have an async implementation. This can expose latent deadlock bugs in your code.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with SQL Server. All of the Dapper Query Async functions are hanging and timing out. I changed them to the standard query functions, and they return results instantly. This is in an ASP.NET MVC project so it's a problem because normally we have async await from the request all the way down.